# Split Strings to change them

Tags: python, string, split

I'm new with python,I'm trying to learn I hope you can help me.
What I'm trying to to is to change week day, something like this.

Today is {Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri} the best day.

**It suppose to change randonly those week days**.
Do you have any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: 1 solution suggestion is to use an array and a random number generator.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
import random
days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri"]
random_choice = random.choice(days)
print("Today is " + random_choice + " the best day.")
```

Comment: Thank you for answer the issue is that it should be with that format, with **{a|b|c}** and not with ["a","b","c"]

I really do now know how to do it :S

Comment: It seems to be a good solution. What do you mean with the {a|b|c} format?

Answer (score 1):

To convert your formatting into a list, use the following code.

```
weekdays = "{Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri}"

weekdays = weekdays[1:-1].split('|')
```

What this code does is assigns the value, `"{Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri}"`, to the variable, `weekdays`. We then remove the first and last characters with `weekdays[1:-1]` and split the string into list iterations with vertical lines being the points of splitting with `.split('|')` and assign our new value to `weekdays`. The final value of weekdays is `['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri']`. I hope that made sense.

You can then take the list value at the end and run it through @MarkyPython's code.